# Convert Currency and Transfer Money through coinbase-ios-SDK in IOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, currency, coinbase-api

I'm installing coinbase-ios-SDK in my application and successfully run Example coinbase IOS App but I cannot understand that how I convert currency and transfer money through coinbase-ios-SDK? How can I access transfer money and currency conversion "API"?

I think this is the API where we can access it in our application:

POST https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/transactions

here is the link below where I get this API:

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money

```
public func setup(with transaction: Transaction) {

    titleLabel.text = transaction.details?.title
    subtitleLabel.text = transaction.details?.subtitle
    amountLabel.text = transaction.amountString
    statusLabel.text = transaction.status

    if let amount = transaction.amount?.amount,
        let amountFloat = Float(amount), amountFloat > 0 {
        amountLabel.textColor = Colors.green
    } else {
        amountLabel.textColor = Colors.darkBlue
    }
    setupStatusIndicator(with: transaction.status)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shared is used to populate a table view cell with an existing transaction. If you want to make your own transaction you will need to call `Coinbase.default.transactionResource.send(...)`.

You can find the source code for the Coinbase SDK [here](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk) in case you have more questions.

Comment: Hi!, Can we use a bank payment method in IOS App like First we get all bank information and then we link this account to Coinbase and after that, we send our money in a bank?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Coinbase, I only looked up how to use the API to help you answer this question but as far as I know, you can only use Coinbase to transfer cryptocurrency, not cash from a bank.